# Excel downloading pictures from hyperlink

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently using this code using the developer console to try to mass download all of the images off the hyperlinks I have in my excel document.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Dim Ret As Long

'~~> This is where the images will be saved. Change as applicable
Const FolderName As String = "C:\Temp\"

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim strPath As String

    '~~> Name of the sheet which has the list
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow '<~~ 2 because row 1 has headers
        strPath = FolderName & ws.Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg"

        Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, ws.Range("B" & i).Value, strPath, 0, 0)

        If Ret = 0 Then
            ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "File successfully downloaded"
        Else
            ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "Unable to download the file"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

It seems that it will download the images if the pic name column I have in column A is something like this - "calculator.jpg"

However, I would like the picture name to be the hyperlink I am using to download the images, aka something like www.hyperlink.com/calculator.jpg

My code seems to not download the images when the hyperlink is in the picture name column, even though it does print in column C "download successful."

If someone could help me I would really appreciate it!

Comment: What is the value say in Col A and in Col B?

Comment: open the excel file and see what is the value say in row 2 so A2 and B2?

Comment: https://www.mbopartners.com/documents/10186/41474/calculator.jpg

Comment: That is for both row 2 A2 and B2

Comment: you can't have the pic name as hyperlink as "/" is not a valid charater for a file name. You have to extract "calculator.jpg" from col A and then use it in the code

Comment: See the answer that I posted

Answer (score 0):

> However, I would like the picture name to be the hyperlink I am using to download the images, aka something like www.hyperlink.com/calculator.jpg

Like I said in the comments above, "You can't have the pic name as hyperlink as "/" is not a valid character for a file name. You have to extract "calculator.jpg" from col A and then use it in the code"

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Dim Ret As Long

'~~> This is where the images will be saved. Change as applicable
Const FolderName As String = "D:\Temp\"

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim MyAr

    '~~> Name of the sheet which has the list
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow '<~~ 2 because row 1 has headers
        MyAr = Split(ws.Range("A" & i).Value, "/")

        '~~> C:\Temp\Calculator.jpg
        strPath = FolderName & MyAr(UBound(MyAr))

        Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, ws.Range("B" & i).Value, strPath, 0, 0)

        If Ret = 0 Then
            ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "File successfully downloaded"
        Else
            ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "Unable to download the file"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```